# Is it the Apollo CM "flowerpot parachute attachment fitting"?

Tags: identify-this-object, recovery, apollo-17

An Apollo 17 recovery image of the top of the CM, ap17-S72-55888 from [ALSJ](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/a17/images17.html#Post).

[image]

**What is the structure inside the red polygon** (drawn by me)? Is it the "flowerpot parachute attachment fitting"?

Left and right of it are two drogue parachute mortars. The white sling with the crane hook is the sea recovery sling used to lift the CM aboard the Ticonderoga recovery ship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is it.

Labeled as such in this image.

[image]

From [Apollo Spacecraft Pyrotechnics](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44723751?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

This picture shows that fitting between the mortars.

[image]

From [Apollo Experience Report, Earth Landing System](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19740003586)

There's a picture (not labeled though) showing the parachute-stowed configuration. I highlighted the first part of the risers in green.

[image]

Picture from [Apollo Spacecraft and Systems Familiarization](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/ApolloSpacecrftSystmsFAM67.pdf) training course

Comment: Excellent selection of images! Thanks a lot.