# What were these bent clamps at the top of Apollo 11 CM used for?

Tags: apollo-11

An image of the top of Apollo 11 CM from [heroicrelics](http://heroicrelics.org/destination-moon/apollo-11/index.html) dscc9638 and dscc9660.

[image]
[image]

What were these bent clamps (marked with green arrows by me) used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the main parachute retention system in the Block II command modules.

> The Block I main-parachute retention flaps were replaced by a series
> of fabric- covered, spring steel straps attached to the upper-deck
> structure. These straps were then chain-laced by an interlocking
> length of cord to loops sewed to the face of the main- parachute
> deployment bag (fig. A-12).

[image]

From [Apollo Experience Report, Earth Landing Systems](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19740003586)

Not labeled but shown here

[image]

From [Apollo Spacecraft and Systems Familiarization](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/ApolloSpacecrftSystmsFAM67.pdf) training course (annotations mine)

Upper and lower sets of straps are visible in this section of the image from this question: [Is it the Apollo CM "flowerpot parachute attachment fitting"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45518/6944)

[image]